# C# - 2 DataTable columns to Dictionary - Distinct Value

Tags: c#, dictionary, datatable

I have a list of text files, I am reading each and with help of split option I am creating a datatable (Name: tbl) with 5 columns (No ID).

Further, creating a datatable with only Column1 and Column5 and converting this into a dictionary as column1 will be a key and column5 will be its value.

Following is the code:

```
        string[] selectedColumns = new[] { "Column1", "Column5" };
        DataTable dt = new DataView(tbl).ToTable(false, selectedColumns);

        dict = dt.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary<DataRow, string, string>(row => row[0].ToString(),
                                   row => row[1].ToString());
```

**Error:**
$exception  {"An item with the same key has already been added."}   System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}

The error arised due to duplication.

```
    dict = dt.AsEnumerable().Distinct().ToDictionary<DataRow, string, string>(row => row[0].ToString(),
                               row => row[1].ToString());
```

Results into the same.

```
dict = dt.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary<DataRow, string, string>(row => row[0].ToString(),
                                           row => row[1].ToString()).Distinct();
```

**Throws an error:** Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

How can I avoid duplication and get only distinct values into the dictionary dict?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that a given value in column 1 will always have the same value in column 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As error states, you need to convert it to `Dictionary`

Try this

```
            dict = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new
            {
                attribute1_name = row.Field<string>(selectedColumns[0]),
                attribute2_name = row.Field<string>(selectedColumns[1])
            }).Distinct().ToDictionary(s => s.attribute1_name, s => s.attribute2_name);
```

Comment: Gives the same error. {"An item with the same key has already been added."} System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}

Comment: This doesn't help because you are creating a dictionary before deduplicating so you will have the problem of duplicate entries still. You need to get distinct values before the first call to ToDictionary.

Comment: @Tango Edited answer, please check now

Comment: Works perfect. My version of the solution `dt = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r=>new {Col1 = r["Column1"]}).Select(r=>r.First()));
tDT = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Column1")).Select(g => g.First()).CopyToDataTable();
dict = tDT.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary<DataRow, string, string>(row => row[0].ToString(),
row => row[1].ToString());`

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try something like this:

```
 dict = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x=> x.<yourColumnName>)
  .Select(group => group.First());
```

and then load into a dictionary.